# Spritekitで、nodeにzRotationをかけると物理的位置がずれます

Tags: swift, spritekit

下記のようにSKSpriteNodeを作って、physicBodyを設定するとちゃんと動きます。
（例えば、これとは別の丸いnodeを作って、下記のslopeの上に落とすと、ちゃんと接触します。）

```
let slope = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))
slope.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
slope.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: slope.frame.size)
slope.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
self.scene?.addChild(slope)
```

しかし、このslopeノードを斜めにしようとして、
`slope.zRotation = CGFloat(10.0 * M_PI / 180.0)`を追加して実行すると、
slopeオブジェクトの見た目とは少し上にphysicalな透明なオブジェクトができてしまい、
slopeノードの上からボールを落とすと、見た目上のslopeノードの板に接触する前に、透明な板にぶつかって転がります。

zRotationを使うと、このようなずれが生じるものなのでしょうか？
今回やりたいことは、斜めの板を作って、上からボールを落とすと板の表面を転がる、ということですが、どのようにすればできるか教えてください。

---

解決しました。下記のように、zRotationを「physicsBodyの設定の前」に記述していたのが不具合の原因でした。
回答者様のコード例のように、physicsBodyを設定した後でzRotationの設定記述することで、問題なく動作しました。ありがとうございました。

不具合のコード例：
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let slope = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))
slope.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 100)
slope.zRotation = CGFloat(10.0 * M_PI / 180.0) //ここで記述したら不具合でした
slope.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: slope.frame.size)
slope.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
addChild(slope)
}

Comment: おっしゃるとおり、順番が変わると、`physicsBody`がずれますね。`SpriteKit`のバグのように思えます。ともあれ解決してなによりです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おっしゃる状態が再現できません。

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let skView = view as! SKView
        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}
```

*GameScene.swift*

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let slope = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))
        slope.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 100)
        slope.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: slope.frame.size)
        slope.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        slope.zRotation = CGFloat(10.0 * M_PI / 180.0)
        addChild(slope)

        let ball = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 32.0, height: 32.0))
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ball.frame.size)
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 90.0, y: 300.0)
        addChild(ball)
    }

}
```

ノード`ball`が円ではなく、正方形なのは、問題と直接関係ないので、容赦ください。
上のコードをiOSシミュレータで動かしてみると、「見た目」のノード`slope`の傾斜に沿って、ノード`ball`が滑り落ちます。

> slopeオブジェクトの見た目とは少し上にphysicalな透明なオブジェクトができてしまい、
>   slopeノードの上からボールを落とすと、見た目上のslopeノードの板に接触する前に、透明な板にぶつかって転がります。

確実にこの状態が発生するコードを、質問文を編集して、掲示してください。